# Is there a way to change the order in which accounts from different websites appear in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I am subscribed to six accounts on Stack Overflow. The problem is that the one that I use most frequently is the sixth one and I have to click *view more* to see it and access it from Stack Overflow.

Is there a way to change the order in which these accounts show up? I have other accounts which I don't use that often and I would prefer them to be the ones I have to click *view more* option for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're talking about Graphic Design, right? The sites are ordered by your rep on those sites. Since you have 1 rep on all the other sites, they are ordered randomly (or by some other sort order which I don't know).

Get some rep on Graphic Design, and it'll come up.

I checked out your profile, and, barring some grammar issues, your posts seem to deserve upvotes (from what little I know of graphic design), but they were drowned out by other posts. I flagged one of them though, it was supposed to be a comment.

Wait a day or two, and once the cache has cleared GD.SE will be somewhere up top :)

Comment: thanks a lot (not for flagging my post but i guess you're just doing you're duty) And yea my grammar is horrible. Im trying to improve but im dyslexic and its pretty slow process for me.

Comment: @Xitcod13: Oh, the flag will get it converted to a comment.. Flags aren't all bad--only the spam/offensive ones. Don't worry, as long as the post is understandable, grammar doesn't matter. I'll fix the grammar in your posts, wait a mo' :)

Comment: thanks a lot! I make sure to read it and learn a think or two. You really helped me a lot!